# popover won't show when tapped on cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i want to use an uitableviewrowaction to show a popoverview, in which the user can select a color. The popover works great when i choose an navigation item as sender. As soon as i change the sender to a tableViewCell, the background turns darker, but the popover won't show. Here's my code

popover presented from nav item

[image]

uitableviewrowaction

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    var colorRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Color", handler:
        { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, path: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("popoverSegue", sender:self.mainTableViewOutlet.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path))
    })

    return [colorRowAction, deleteRowAction]
}
```

prepare for segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)       
{
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
        colorPopover = segue.destinationViewController as SBColorPopover
        colorPopover.modalPresentationStyle =      
UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        colorPopover.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        colorPopover.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Check if self.mainTableViewOutlet.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) returns nil, and Im not seeing you're doing anything with sender in prepareForSegue

Comment: you are right, i had to call colorPopover.popoverViewController.sourceRect = sender.frame in the prepare for segue method. Now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Since i called performSegue programatically, i have to define the sourceRect of the popoverViewController:

```
colorPopover = segue.destinationViewController as SBColorPopover
        colorPopover.modalPresentationStyle =     
UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        colorPopover.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
//define sourceRect
        colorPopover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect =
sender!.frame
        colorPopover.delegate = self
```